# r apply loop to create amortization schedule

Tags: r, loops, apply, amortization

I need to create an amortization calculation in R. The calculation for the first row works fine, but all subsequent calculations need to use values that are either calculated or in the first row and I can not get the loop to work.

```
df <- data.frame(
  LoanID = c("LN-000249", "LN-000249", "LN-000249", "LN-000249"),
  apply_date = c("2015-07-30 UTC", "2015-09-03 UTC", "2015-11-09 UTC", "2015-11-18 UTC"),
  pmt_amt = c(17292.45, 17153.90, 18100.00,   107.23),
  rows = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  calc_days = c(41, 35, 67,  9)
                 )
```

Say the loan is valued at 50000 and the interest rate was .08 percent

```
ln_amt = 50000
ln_interest_rate = .08
```

**calculations for first row**

```
df$interestAmt <- ln_amt * ln_interest_rate / 360 * df$calc_days
df$principalAmt <- df$pmt_amt - df$interestAmt
df$balance <- ln_amt - df$principalAmt
```

**calculations for all other rows**

```
df$interestAmt <- (new balance found in previous row or current balance calculation value) * ln_interest_rate / 360 * df$calc_days
df$principalAmt <- df$pmt_amt - df$interestAmt
df$balance <- (new balance found in previous row ) - df$principalAmt
 # or it is equal to the (ln_amt - cumsum(df$principalAmt) )
```

I need to figure out how to do the calculations for all rows and not just the first row and create a dataframe.  I need to do the amortization calculations based on the current balance and calculation days and the actual payment made and not a calculated payment value.  Thus I can't use a formula to get these values.
I can't seem to get the values correct for interestAmt or balance on rows 2-4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2<-df %>% mutate(interestAmt <- ln_amt * ln_interest_rate/360*calc_days,
principalAmt = pmt_amt - interestAmt,
balance  = ln_amt - principalAmt) %>% mutate(interestAmt =(ifelse(is.na(lag(balance,1)),balance,lag(balance,1))) * ln_interest_rate/360*calc_days,
principalAmt = pmt_amt - interestAmt,
balance = lag(balance,1) - principalAmt)
```

Isn't the best approach as it does compute the initial balance and interestamount for all the rows and then overwrites, the overhead should not be much if your dataset is small

Comment: I like the approach, but the calculations it produces are not correct.  The balance does not calculated correctly and thus the interestAmt does not calculate correct.  I am going to try to use your approach and see if I can get the calculations right.  Yes you are right the datasets are small. I know how to do this in SAS I just can not figure out the order of calculations in R. Ugh!

Comment: If you would have explained what do you mean by _new balance found in previous row or current balance calculation value_ maybe the solution could have been more accurate. A re-producable example always helps