# Is an amortization table posible without an for loop in R?

Tags: r, finance, amortization

I need to create several amortization tables. I did it, but it takes a lot because there are a lot of data.
As you know R is not good with for loops, so im trying to optimize the time invested in that operation.

I have the for loop and it works

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
              if (df[i,"aux"]== 1) {
                     df[i,"Interest"] <-df[i,"Original_mount"] * df[i,"MonthlyRate"]
                     df[i,"Capital"] <- df[i,"instalement"]-df[i,"Interest"]
                     df[i,"final_balance"]<-df[i,"inicial_balance"] - df[i,"Capital"]
              } else {
                     df[i,"inicial_balance"]<-df[i-1,"final_balance"]
                     df[i,"Interest"] <-df[i,"inicial_balance"] * df[i,"MonthlyRate"]
                     df[i,"Capital"] <- df[i,"instalement"]-df[i,"Interest"]
                     df[i,"final_balance"]<-df[i,"inicial_balance"] - df[i,"Capital"]
```

and i try mutate, apply, purr and nothing works.

Mutate: because is an iterative process and mutate make all the column
apply: because the output is a list
Purrr: all the output is NA

Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: This sort of thing is often possible using `cumsum` and `cumprod` - e.g. - compound interest can be calculated using `cumprod` as the interest is cumulatively applied at each row - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50593439/calculating-compound-interest-with-vector-of-rates/50593687 . You might want to provide some example data of a couple of rows so people have a target input and output to work with.

Comment: Have you searched here for "[r] amortization"? It looked like there have been some relevant questions and answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68398411/how-do-i-replace-a-for-loop-in-r-with-vector-functions-in-dataframe-calculation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70833384/developing-a-custom-function-of-loops-for-forecasting-any-loan, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52197550/how-to-use-apply-when-each-calculated-value-depends-on-previous-value/52200744#52200744, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36472723/r-apply-loop-to-create-amortization-schedule

Comment: What does "lot of data" mean here? 1 thousand rows, 1 million rows, 1 billion rows?

Comment: R for loops are not especially slow, typically slowness is due to lack of proper initialisation leading to slowdowns when expanding the result accumulator on the fly, this is likely not an issue when iterating over an existing structure without changing said structure.  for the fastest possible computation you might look to have your code written in cpp and integrate it with R via RCPP or such (maybe Rust...) ;

Comment: There would seem to be an easy quick improvement you could get by moving the if that checks first row out of the loop. you should simply run the code for the first row so that the first row is processed, and then your loop should be over the second row to the end, this way you can skip as many if() checks as you had rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use known formulas for

installment: ( A * [( i * (1 + i)^n) / ((1 + i)^n - 1)]),

the first capital payment: (P_1= A * i /((1 + i)^n - 1)),

and the subsequent capital payments: (P_n = P_{n-1} * (1 + i))

This reduzes time and avoid the loop. Try this:

```
ii <- 0.12/12 #MonthlyRate
A <- 20000 # Original_mount
nm=60 # Months

df3 <- data.frame(n = 0:nm)
df3$final_balance  <-  df3$Capital <- df3$Interest <- df3$instalement  <- 0
df3$instalement[-1] = A*((ii*(1+ii)^nm)/((1+ii)^nm-1))
df3$Capital[2] <- ii*A/((1+ii)^nm-1)
df3$Capital[-c(1:2)] <- cumprod(1+rep(ii,nm-1))*df3$Capital[2]
df3$Interest=df3$instalement - df3$Capital
df3$final_balance = A - cumsum(df3$Capital)
```

Using library(microbenchmark). I call your procedure "proc1" and this alternative "proc2". The improvement is very clear!

```
> mbm
Unit: microseconds
  expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq     max neval cld
 proc1 19106.6 19443.70 20727.336 19893.35 21620.9 25979.4   100 a  
 proc2   168.2   199.50   217.734   211.90   233.7   422.2   100   b

> print(df3[c(1:5,(nrow(df3)-5):nrow(df3)),])
    n instalement   Interest  Capital final_balance
1   0       0.000   0.000000   0.0000  2.000000e+04
2   1     444.889 200.000000 244.8890  1.975511e+04
3   2     444.889 197.551110 247.3378  1.950777e+04
4   3     444.889 195.077732 249.8112  1.925796e+04
5   4     444.889 192.579620 252.3093  1.900565e+04
56 55     444.889  25.783435 419.1055  2.159238e+03
57 56     444.889  21.592379 423.2966  1.735941e+03
58 57     444.889  17.359414 427.5295  1.308412e+03
59 58     444.889  13.084118 431.8048  8.766070e+02
60 59     444.889   8.766070 436.1229  4.404841e+02
61 60     444.889   4.404841 440.4841  2.182787e-11
```

Comment: thank you. This is just what I need. I've tried with changes in the code but I didn't know these formulas.

Comment: Nice! , if possible mark the question as solved! :)